# How to force exceptions and errors to print in AWS Lambda that is forcing the Lambda function to run twice?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a AWS lambda function (written in python 3.7) that is triggered when a specific JSON file is uploaded from a server to a s3 bucket. Currently I have trigger set on AWS lambda for a PUT request with the specific suffix of the file.

The issue is the lambda function is running twice everytime the JSON file is uploaded once to the s3 bucket. I confirmed via cloudwatch that every instance of any additional runs is roughly 10seconds to 1min apart and each run has an unique requestID.

To troubleshoot, I confirmed that JSON input is coming from one bucket and outputs are being written to completely separate bucket. I silenced all warnings coming from pandas, and do not see any errors that would occur in the code pop up in cloudwatch. I also have changed the retry attempts from 2 to 0.

The function also has the following metrics when it is running, with a timeout set at 40seconds and memory size set to 1920MB. There should be enough time and memory for the function to use:

```
Duration: 1216.03 ms    Billed Duration: 1300 ms    Memory Size: 1920 MB    Max Memory Used: 164 MB
```

I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

How can I force AWS Lambda to display the issues or errors it is encountering that is forcing the Lambda function to run multiple times in my python code or where ever the issue is occurring?

Comment: Can you share your lambda code, or some minimal reproducible version of it showing the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "outputs are being written to completely separate bucket"? What is the code doing? Do the logs show any error messages?

Comment: Just as a test, what happens if you remove the code from the Lambda function (eg just make it print something, then exit)? Does the function still run twice? Then, start adding code back until you can identify what is possibly causing it to run twice. It might be due to the code returning an error. Also, have you looked in AWS CloudTrail to see whether the two executions are listed?

Comment: Different request IDs suggests that it's two different S3 events. Any chance you are accidentally putting/uploading the same object twice, or somehow overwriting the original object with the same contents? You could use CloudTrail to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my code was throwing an error, but for some reason cloudwatch was not showing the error.